# uninstalling ransack gem gives 'cannot load such file --ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, ransack

I want to use elasticsearch gem and after installing it and setting it all up, I went on uninstalling the ransack gem.

I tried first with removing it from the Gemfile (and gemfile.lock) and ran bundle install.
After starting the server with webrick, I got
`'cannot load such file --ransack'`

I also did `gem uninstall ransack` and `bundle exec uninstall ransack` but I get the same error.

Can you help me out on this?

Comment: uninstall and remove from gemfile..then bundle again to update

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to remove

```
require 'ransack'
```

from everywhere in your project.